Adding Multiple Conditions to a SUMIF
I'm confused with a Google Sheet that I have going. I am trying to add multiple conditions to one Sumif. I have one cell that is conditional to a name. (If this cell equals this name, and if this cell says 'yes' or 'no') then, add a value from the cell horizontal to all of the cells added to the cell I am calculating for.
Does this make sense?
The current formula I am using (that I keep getting errors for) is: =SUMIFS(B5:B1003, "Stuart Rowe", E5:E1003, "No", C5:C1003 )
I keep getting a #VALUE! error. I have spent over 30 minutes looking on different sites including this one, and haven't found the answer.
I tried adding more commas after a regular SUMIF equation, and also tried using the SUMIFS equation as well, but I wasn't able to get it to work without getting errors such as: N/A!, #VALUE!, and #ERROR!.

Thank you so much! My form works perfectly now!

Welcome to stackoverflow. I'm guessing that this response is for my answer, please consider on clicking the accept button on the left (check icon).  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.

Proper Usage of the SUMIFS function
Based on your formula, it seems that your usage of SUMIFS is incorrect.
The parameters of the SUMIFS function are:

SUMIFS(sum_range, criteria_range1, criterion1, [criteria_range2, criterion2, ...])


Since you have not posted a sample set of data, I used the following sample data:

Here is the formula:
=SUMIFS(E5:E, B5:B, "Stuart Rowe", C5:C, "No")

The first parameter E5:E is the range of cells to be summed. The second parameter B5:B is the range to check against Stuart Rowe which is the first criterion and also the third parameter. The fourth parameter C5:C and fifth parameter No are additional ranges and criteria that will also be checked.

Reference:

SUMIFS function


If my assumptions are incorrect, feel free to send a comment so that I can edit my answer above and connect it to your spreadsheet data.
